# How to implement "malloc" in Wasm

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I am learning `WebAssembly` now and I find that the external function (libc or third party function) can't be accessed by Wasm world easily (using import is a general solution).

I'm trying to use `emcc` to compile my source code into wasm but `malloc` and `free` are widely used in my source code. I don't think that importing `malloc` and `free` from real world is practicable.

So, I'm pretty curious about how to implement `malloc` in wasm world. I have already known how the malloc works in `glibc`:using brk() or sbrk() to extend heap and some memory management for the liner address. But in wasm world I think it impossible to call `brk()` or `sbrk()` to get the liner address.

Is it reasonable to use global var to implement `malloc` like this ?

```c
u_char mem[10240];


void *wasm_malloc(size_t num)
{
    /*get the free mem idx*/
    return &mem[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Wait, you don't need to do that.

> I don't think that importing malloc and free from real world is practicable.

Incorrect. That's exactly the point of using Emscripten. Emscripten is not just a C/C++ to Wasm compiler, but a complete toolchain that includes a web runtime and its own libc specifically designed for running C/C++ program for web browsers with minimal source code modifications.

Emscripten libc is a heavily modified fork of [musl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl). It implements/emulates wide range of standard C libraries (including `malloc`, `sbrk`) and POSIX APIs (like pthread and BSD socket), except some APIs that doesn't make sense in a Wasm environment like `exec` and `fork`. By using `emcc` command, you will link those libc ports out of the box. So feel free just using `malloc` - you don't need to do anything!

If you are still wondering how to implement `malloc` for Emscripten, Emscripten has [two options of `malloc` implementations](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/42a634fffeafef979b3cf4134b983225229af0db/src/settings.js#L109) - dlmalloc and emmalloc.

[dlmalloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#dlmalloc) is a famous malloc implementation. glibc also uses a forked version of it. You can see Emscripten's version of dlmalloc [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/system/lib/dlmalloc.c).

emmalloc might be more interesting to you. It's a simple and compact malloc implementation for web enviroment, designed by the Emscripten team. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/system/lib/emmalloc.c).

Comment: Source changed to https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/system/lib/emmalloc.c