# Export a structure from C to wasm?

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I have a header file with the following declarations:

```
typedef struct {
        double *vals;
        int len;
} List;

typedef struct {
        List *list;
        int sample;
} MarkedList;
```

I'm compiling a C file that includes these definitions and a function that takes a `const *MarkedList` with:

```sh
clang --target=wasm32 -nostdlib -Wl,--export-all -Wl,--no-entry src/filename.c -o target/res/filename.wasm
```

I'm loading that file with:

```js
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('res/mean.wasm'), {})
.then(results => {
    console.log(results)
});
```

The console then shows me a wasm module with instance.exports containing the function I defined, but *not* the structures. How can I access the structures from my javascript `results` object?

Comment: You can't export classes or structs, only instances, i.e. symbols.   If you create global instance of a `MarkedList` you should be able to export that (i.e. its address in memory)

Comment: @sbc100 oh, thanks. How would I allocate or instantiate a struct in JS?

Comment: There are several ways.   The lowest level way would be to call `Module._malloc`.  There are also higher level solutions for binding such as embind: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v changed a lot of code in figuring out how to address this, but I'll try to write out a summary of my overall solutions as best I can. Firstly, I switched to emcc over clang so that standard library C features (like malloc) work in wasm (see [How to implement "malloc" in Wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032577/how-to-implement-malloc-in-wasm)). While it's a very heavy-handed solution, I *believe* LTO can cut down on some unused features.

Secondly, I've done my best to encapsulate the API of the `List` and `MarkedList` structs such that only useful functions that communicate with solely number types (including pointers) are exported to the JS, in compliance with the WebAssembly standard. So a `List *malloc_list(void)` and a `void push_list(List *l, double v)` make sense in this context, but anything with an API depending on the in-memory representation of a struct (for instance, to access an indivdual field) would be impossible.

So while there is no widely-applicable way to export a struct, there are workarounds that keep as much as possible in the C and as little as possible in the JS, and I was able to accomplish what I needed from the List and MarkedList structs.

Comment: > So while there is no widely-applicable way to export a struct,

If you're using Emscripten, there is - Embind allows exporting structs, classes and more. https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html

Comment: @RReverser  I came across that page, my understanding is that it only applies to C++ classes, which ends up in *basically the solution presented above*, but with C++ instead of C

Comment: That's correct, but now you need to manually provide custom bindings on both C and JS sides. Instead, you can create a cpp file just for the Embind annotations and compile + link it along with your C codebase, and let Emscripten do the exporting and binding job for you. It's mostly a question of scaling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kinda old question, but I have been using what I call "magic classes" for plain (no emscripten) wasm, made with wasi-sdk (which includes a malloc/free) but there are a few malloc implementations for wasm, like "walloc", which is small & standalone.

Even with emscripten, it can be nice for exposing a JS interface that needs to pass structs to C functions. I used this style on [raylib-wasm](https://github.com/konsumer/raylib-wasm) to expose the raylib API to web JS, using a familiar syntax.

The essential trick is to set all the fields to mess with the memory directly, using addresses.

Say we have a struct like this:

```c
typedef Color {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char a;
}
```

```js
// do your WASM init here, however you do that
// you need to expose malloc & memory, and should probably expose free
const api = {}
const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBytes, api)
const mod = instance.exports
const view = new DataView(mod.memory.buffer)

class Color {
  constructor(init={}, address) {
    this._size = 4 // bytes
    this._address = address || mod.malloc(this._size)
    for (const k of Object.keys(init)) {
      this[k] = init[k]
    }
  }
  get r() {
    return view.getUint8(this._address)
  }
  get g() {
    return view.getUint8(this._address + 1)
  }
  get b() {
    return view.getUint8(this._address + 2)
  }
  get a() {
    return view.getUint8(this._address + 3)
  }
  set r(v) {
    view.setUint8(this._address, v)
  }
  set g(v) {
    view.setUint8(this._address + 1, v)
  }
  set b(v) {
    view.setUint8(this._address + 2, v)
  }
  set a(v) {
    view.setUint8(this._address + 3, v)
  }
}
```

Now, you can do stuff like this:

```js
// these do a fresh allocation
const BLACK = new Color()
const WHITE = new Color({ r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 255 })

// this makes a color-object from an address
const c = new Color({}, address)

// you can get/set them just like a plain js object
console.log(BLACK.a)
BLACK.a = 255

// you can use them with your wasm by pulling _address
mod.clear_screen(BLACK._address)

// here is a wrapper, for nicer user-function
export function clear_screen(color) {
  mod.clear_screen(color._address)
}

// free the mem when you are done
mod.free(BLACK._address)
```

I wrote [a library](https://github.com/konsumer/cmem_helpers) that does similar, for simple-to-use structs like this, here is an example:

```js
import memhelpers from 'cmem_helpers'
const wasmBytes = '...'

const env = {
  // add your imported API here
}

const mod = (await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBytes, { env })).instance.exports

const { structClass, setString, getString } = memhelpers(mod.memory.buffer, mod.malloc)

const Color = structClass({
  r: 'Uint8',
  g: 'Uint8',
  b: 'Uint8',
  a: 'Uint8'
})

// usage is same as above
const BLACK = new Color({r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 255})
mod.clear_screen(BLACK._address)
```

Additionally, `setString`/`getString` are useful lil utils for messing with C-strings over wasm, in a similar way, and not having to encode/decode and worry too much about string-length.